# Can't connect to server with send-MailMessage in Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, credentials

I have been trying to create an email which will be sent from a gmail account when a PoweShell file is run. However I am unable to connect to the server when using the `send-MailMessage` method. 
I have the following code:

```
$from = "blondedavid@gmail.com"
$to = "blondedavid@gmail.com"
$subject = "The subject of your email"
$body = "This is just a test mail to verify the working of CMD"
$attachment = "C:\Users\37.csv"
$smtp = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("blondedavid@gmail.com", "xxx");

send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -Credential $SMTPClient -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -Attachment $attachment -Priority high
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Send-MailMessage Cmdlet with wrong credential parameter. 
From the commandlet help, it accepts a `pscredential`.

```
SYNTAX
Send-MailMessage [-To] <string[]> [-Subject] <string> [[-Body] <string>] [[-SmtpServer] <string>] -From <string> [-Attachments <string[]>] [-Bcc <string[]>] [-BodyAsHtml] [-Encoding <Encoding>] [-Cc <string[]>] [-DeliveryNotificationOpt
ion {None | OnSuccess | OnFailure | Delay | Never}] [-Priority {Normal | Low | High}] [-ReplyTo <string[]>] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseSsl] [-Port <int>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

You are passing the the `$SMTPClient` which is `Net.Mail.SmtpClient`

Just create a Pscredential object and pass it to `-Credential`. Also remove the `$SMTPClient` altogether.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by creating a Pscredential object and passing it to -Credential? Should it be along the lines of ```$Pscredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("blondedavid@gmail.com", "xxx");``` and then passed to -Credential?

Answer (score 0):

```
$from = "blondedavid@gmail.com"
$to = "blondedavid@gmail.com"
$subject = "The subject of your email"
$body = "This is just a test mail to verify the working of CMD"
$attachment = "C:\Users\37.csv"
$smtp = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("blondedavid@gmail.com", "xxx");


$Msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$Msg.From = $from
foreach ($MailTo in $to) {
    $Msg.To.Add($MailTo)
    }
$Msg.Subject = $subject
$Msg.Body = $body
if ($attachment -is [array]) {
    foreach ($MailAtthPath in $attachment) {
        if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($MailAtthPath)) {
            $MailAtth = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($MailAtthPath)
            $Msg.Attachments.Add($MailAtth)
            }
        }
    }
$SMTPClient.Send($Msg)
```